# Android app development any suggestions?

Tags: android, xml

So im making an app that creates events by filling in a form then you can share it.

The Question is that my app  displays 9 buttons and each button corresponds to different categories of events. I want each layout of the new activity to have in top a banner with the name categorie of the event.. so should I do a different XML layout for each categorie? any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML layout is usually for a single screen or for a repeating element on a screen (e.g. for a list item). If your screens have some parts that can be reused (e.g. many screens with Ok/Cancel buttons at the bottom or some title bar on all the screens ) then you may want to have those repeating parts as seperate XML files and include them in each screen.
Other than that I can't say anything because can't understand the question fully. 
Perhaps you shall just create your layout(s) first - a separate layout for each screen - and then optimize.

Comment: thanks for the help. I decided to create one XML per categorie.

Answer (score 2):

If your layout is the same for each categories, i.e each category show the same elements at the same places, then stick with a single xml layout (that can be splitted, of course).

Then layout content will be set in your java code.